# change chrome print preview default options

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In chrome print preview, under Options tab, the default is having Headers and footers ticked on. Is it not possible to set it default to off via javascript / chrome extension / anything outside telling user to do it manually?

OR is it possible to remove the date displayed there?

[image]

Comment: Hey @jaycode, did you ever figure this one out?  I am trying to do the same thing.  Looking for a way to turn off the header and footer by default.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In short, yes you can control this behavior.  It is actually very bizzarre -- as appears to have been originally answered in the question "*[In Google Chrome, Docs Can Control Headers and Footers from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672739/in-google-chrome-google-docs-can-control-headers-and-footers-from-javascript-d)*" The secret to this behavior is in the `@page` CSS property*.

If you set this exact style:

```
    @page { margin: 0; }
```

Then you get the desired behavior, the headers & footers option disappears:

[image: Google Chrome print dialog without headers & footers option]

This appears to be an undocumented behavior of Google Chrome, or at least not widely known -- cursory digging in to their developer docs garnered nothing. Google uses it themselves throughout their own web-apps, so it's probably not a secret, but I couldn't find any official notes on it.

Notably, a margin of `0` does not simply disable the "headers & footers" option, it actually causes it to disappear from the menu entirely ( by quickly folding ).

Experimentation reveals that other variations of this do not have the same effect.  For example `margin: 0; margin-left: 10cm;` does not cause this behavior.

If you do choose to implement this solution, it means forfeiting the ability to control those margins through the `@page` property -- you should instead be controlling them as part of a CSS print-media stylesheet.  Bummer that Chrome kind of destroys the `@page` property this way.  That said, `FF` still does not support `@page` ( as of now ) so it's not a perfect solution to begin with.

---

*More information about the `@page` property

The `@page` CSS is supposed to control the margins of the printed page, the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-box) says:

> The page box is a rectangular region that contains two areas:
>
> - The page area. The page area includes the boxes laid out on that page.
>     The edges of the first page area establish the rectangle that is the
>     initial containing block of the document. The canvas background is
>     painted within and covers the page area.
> - The margin area, which
>     surrounds the page area. The page margin area is transparent.

Most modern [browsers support](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/@page) the `@page` CSS property.  Firefox is the standout who doesn't, though they do fully [document it in their developer resources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@page), and their issue tracker [has a ticket for this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=115199) that goes back 10 years. The most recent action on it was today, so perhaps FF will provide `@page` support soon.

Comment: Beware that if you remove the margins, even if you add margin to the top of the page to compensate, if you print more than 1 page you are in trouble.

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't have to set that *exact* style. For example, you can do `@page { margin: 0 auto; }` if you want to keep the left and right margins on the page.

Comment: What will we do without this site? Just awesome!!

Answer (score 2):

Well the page is just html, so if you can execute javascript on the page then yes you can do this. I don't recall whether Chrome extensions can bind to internal pages though. Do you know how to write a Chrome Extension? If so this would be easy enough to test.

```
document.getElementById('header-footer').checked = false;
```

Comment: Good answer! The right command for Chrome last version now is `document.getElementsByClassName('header-footer-checkbox')[0].checked=false`
But it only worked running it in console, after print page was loaded... Strange thing is that when I reopen the print page the settings is checked again and it not happen when the checkebox is unmarked by a user click.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome only allows you to [override](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html) couple specific `chrome://` pages and the print page is not one of them. You are also limited to [injecting](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) scripts into a couple of specific schemes.

> A match pattern is essentially a URL that begins with a permitted scheme (http, https, file, or ftp)

Answer (score 0):

In current version of Google Chrome, Print Preview now have option to include or not header and footer, as well as define margins and include or not background colors and images. Just update your browser to the last version.

Comment: But chrome still can't control whether we need to hide URL/Page number or title just like in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Current Version of 31 remembers setting of of whether you want it two sided, headers and footers and printing of background images and colors but far as I can tell it won't remember margin settings.

Answer (score 0):

Note for myself Code template from https://excessivelyadequate.com/posts/print.html tested and working

```
@page {
    /* Browser default, customizable by the user in the print dialogue. */
    size: auto;

    /* Default, but explicitly in portrait or landscape orientation and not user-
    customizable. In my instance of Chrome, this is a vertical or horizontal letter
    format, but you might find something different depending on your locale. */
    size: portrait;
    size: landscape;

    /* Predefined format, can be coupled with an orientation. */
    size: letter;
    size: A4;
    size: A4 landscape;

    /* Custom, with same width and height. */
    size: 10cm;
    size: 420px;
    size: 6in;

    /* Different width and height. */
    size: 640px 360px;
    size: 20cm 15cm;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like that there is no way to do such thing.

Comment: Probably because this isn't accurate.